# Are there other VNC servers for macOS other than the built in one?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

The built in VNC server is not sufficient for my needs as I cannot change settings of the VNC server.

I tried to run Vine Server (OSXvnc) but the application crashes on launch.

Are there any other VNC servers that run on macOS?

---

Edit-

When I connect to the built-in VNC server, I observe that it is slow. I tried to make the VNC connection faster by reducing the color level of the VNC connection so that less bandwidth is used. However, the built-in VNC server refuses to connect.

I am looking for VNC server which supports connections with reduced color level so that the VNC connection is faster.

Comment: It would be useful if you explained what about the built-in version doesn't satisfy your requirements… is it simply that you cannot change settings? What settings do you need to change?

Comment: I have edited the question to include why the built in VNC server does not meet my requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there are no other freely available, generic VNC servers for macOS besides the built-in one and the OSXvnc program.

There exist a commercial VNC server from TightVNC, but it is not generic in the sense that it allows VNC access to your macOS desktop - rather it is to be built in to a specific application to allow remote access to that only.

One thing you could try is a newer "fork" of OSXvnc (or rather just seem to be some guys providing updates on the seemingly otherwise abandoned OSXvnc project) here:

https://github.com/stweil/OSXvnc

There are even some pull-requests with bugfixes for a few bugs, so you might be lucky that one of those fixes your crash.